# Дан файл,содержащий фамилии студентов и их хобби.Создать новый файл, содержащий итоговую таблицу вида:Название хобби;Количество студентов с этим хобби

Tags: visual-c++

```css
#include <iostream>#include <fstream>#include <sstream>#include <string>#include <map>#include <locale>#include <optional>int main() {
  // Открываем исходный файл для чтения
  std: :wifstream inFile(L"students.txt");
  // Создаем карту для подсчета хобби
  std: :map<std::wstring, int> hobbies;
  // Читаем файл построчно
  std: :wstring line;
  while (std: :getline(inFile, line)) {
    // Создаем строковый поток для разбора строки
    std::wistringstream ss(line);
    // Читаем фамилию и хобби из строкового потока
    std: :wstring name, hobby;
    std: :getline(ss, name, L':');
    while (std: :getline(ss, hobby, L',')) {
      // Убираем пробелы в начале и конце хобби
      hobby.erase(hobby.begin(), std::find_if(hobby.begin(), hobby.end(), [](wchar_t ch) {
        return !std::iswspace(ch);
      }
      ));
      hobby.erase(std::find_if(hobby.rbegin(), hobby.rend(), [](wchar_t ch) {
        return !std: :iswspace(ch);
      }
      ).base(), hobby.end());
      // Добавляем хобби в карту
      ++hobbies[hobby];
    }
  }
  // Открываем новый файл для записи
  std::wofstream outFile(L"hobbies.txt");
  // Записываем заголовок таблицы
  outFile << L"Название хобби,Количество студентов с этим хобби\n";
  // Перебираем карту и записываем данные в файл
  for (const auto& hobby: hobbies) {
    outFile << hobby.first << L',' << hobby.second << L'\n';
  }
  // Закрываем файлы
  inFile.close();
  outFile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ок, а что дальше?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и [*минимальный код*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.